# How to change wifi hotspot state on android with targetSdkVersion >=23?

Tags: android, wifi, android-permissions

When I try to run android wifi hot spot programmaticaly on android devices api >= 23 it does not work until I lower targetSdkVersion to be less than 23. I guess it happens because of runtime permissions introduced in Marshmallow. But I did not find what kind of runtime permissions should I ask for turning wifi hot spot on/off. I use this class to control wifi hot spot:

```
public class ApManager {
//check whether wifi hotspot on or off
public static boolean isApOn(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(wifimanager);
    }
    catch (Throwable ignored) {}
    return false;
}

// toggle wifi hotspot on
public static boolean turnHotSpotOn(Context context) {
    if(isApOn(context)) {
        return true;
    }
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();

    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    wc.allowedProtocols.clear();

    wc.SSID = "mynetwork";
    wc.preSharedKey  = "mypassword";
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wc.hiddenSSID = false;

    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

    int netId = wifimanager.addNetwork(wc);

    if (netId != -1 ) {
        wifimanager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    }
    wifimanager.saveConfiguration();

    try {
        // if WiFi is on, turn it off
        if (wifimanager.isWifiEnabled()){
            wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        method.invoke(wifimanager, wc, true);
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

// toggle wifi hotspot off
public static boolean turnHotSpotOff(Context context) {
    if(!isApOn(context)) {
        return true;
    }
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    try {
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        method.invoke(wifimanager, null, false);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. To use WifiHotSpot on Marshmallow and above you are supposed to use this code to ask for write permissions:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 200);

                    }
                }
```

Manifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission  
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```